# Search mechanism is not working in Html Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working on search mechanism in html, it is working when i search the data at first time. if i search for next data, it wont search as expected. If i search with empty data, it wont display actual table(which displayed at initial time).

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DHJ79/

```
Even any better pointer is also welcome, if my below code is not good.
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style> td{border: thin solid;} </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function searchTable(inputVal) { 
        var inputVal = document.getElementById('searchdata').value;
            $('.table').html($('.table').html().replace(RegExp(inputVal, 'g'), '<span class="showthis">' + inputVal + '<span>'));
            $("tr").css('display', 'none');
            $(".showthis").parent().parent().css('display', '');
        }

    function addList(){

        var table = "";
        table += "<table class='table'>";
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td>S.no</td>";
        table += "<td>Name</td>";
        table += "<td>Gender</td>";

        table += "</tr>";
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
            table += "<td>Name"+i+"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+( i > 5 ? "Male" : "Female")+"</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</table>";
        var body = document.getElementById("ListContainer");
        body.innerHTML = table;
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="addList();">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="searchTable();" />
        <input id="searchdata" type="text" />
        <div id="ListContainer" > </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Advance thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/v98De/).

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('searchdata').value;
    if (inputVal == "") {
        $('.hideThis').removeClass('hideThis');
    } else {
        $('tr').addClass('hideThis');
        $('tr:has(td:contains(' + inputVal + '))').removeClass('hideThis');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.. It is also work perfect... So simple too. Thanks a lot for your post.

Answer (score 1):

modify your search function as follows:

```
function searchTable(inputVal) { 
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('searchdata').value;
   if(inputVal){ //check for valid searches
        //addList();
        $('.table').html($('.table').html().replace(RegExp(inputVal, 'g'), '<span class="showthis">' + inputVal + '<span>'));
        $("tr").css('display', 'none');
        $(".showthis").parent().parent().css('display', '');
  }
  else{
    addList(); // if you don't want to reinitialize table on empty searches skip this
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, its works. Any other better way to do this (Search mechanism). Even i don't like the code which i wrote, it wont seems to be good one.

Comment: @Hariharan updated the code, now it'll work not only for the first search. would be nice if u can accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot boss... still i need to regain the table when i enter with empty data without calling addList() function.

Comment: @Hariharan if you want to regain the search, just remove the addList(), but how are you planning to allow the user to go back to the initial stage? currently an empty search would do, or perhaps a reset button?
if you don't want that functionality then remove both calls to addList in search function..